# structops - how to make argument optional based on boolean flag

Tags: rust, clap, structopt

I have program that accepts 2 boolean flags `-d` for decode and `-e` for encode. However, if `-e` is specified, additional message string needs to be provided (message to encode). This string should not be present if `-d` is specified. How can I accomplish this using structops?

Here is what I have tried:

```
#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name="encode_test", about="encodes messages")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(short="e", long="encode")]
    encode: bool,

    #[structopt(requires("encode"))]
    message: String,

    #[structopt(short="d", long="decode")]
    decode: bool,
}
```

running the program using `cargo run -- -e "test message"` works fine, but `cargo run -- -d` gives me the error that `<message>` and `--encode` arguments were not provided.

How can I require `<message>` only if `-e` is present?

I have also tried the following:

```
#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name="encode_test", about="encodes messages")]
struct Opt {
    #[structopt(short="d", long="decode", required_unless("encode"))]
    decode: bool,

    // I've tried using conflicts_with("decode") here as well, same panic
    #[structopt(short="e", long="encode", required_unless("decode"))]
    encode: String, //does not panic if I change type here from string to bool
}
```

Which again, works for `-e message` but panics when specifying only `-d` parameter

Comment: Have you tried using an `Option<String>` for the encode argument?

Comment: @Jmb that solved it. Thank you

Comment: Alternatively, using [subcommands](https://docs.rs/structopt/0.3.18/structopt/#subcommands)  instead of flags could be a good idea.